# multi-thread I2C synchronization

Tags: i2c, freertos

I am using an ESP32 board to communicate with an LCD and an I/O expander using an I2C bus. I am running a FreeRTOS based code.

I am using 2 separate threads for the LCD and I/O expander each to concurrently access them. I am trying to use a mutex to implement thread-safe I2C. Do I need to install and delete the I2C drivers(basically setting slave address) within each mutex, every time I enter a thread, since they are 2 different slave addresses?

Is there a better way to perform concurrent i2c communication?

Thanks

Comment: This is a nightmare in the general case.  Been there, done that, don't WANT the fricking T-shirt!

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I didn't get the T-shirt reference though..

Comment: There's a line: "Been there, done that, got the T-shirt."  Variations exist.

Comment: Haha. Does that mean you faced the issue and resolved it somehow?

Comment: It means I've been down that road, fought with such a driver (written by someone else).  I got it working and I never want to see it again.

Comment: Looks like I'm struggling with the same situation. Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: OK, Janka's answer below is the way to do it.  Spend some time looking at all of the i2C devices you are going to use, and some time on devices you MIGHT want to use in the future, so you don't paint yourself into a corner that will be very painful to escape.

Answer (score 6):

The best way would be implementing an I²C worker thread that has a fifo holding several transactions. Each transaction is an array of several transfers, each one with a device address (including R/W), the number of bytes to write/read and a pointer to a data buffer. The thread reads such a transaction and issues start (and repeated start) conditions for each transfer, do the transfer, next transfer(s), finally stop condition. That's implementable in about 50 short lines of C code, including the typedefs.

Comment: This. The I2C interface itself should never directly change hands. You can't context switch in the middle of a transfer, for example. Handle it in a dedicated manner, then use queues to communicate with the other threads.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to firmware development. I am currently using existing library functions developed for the LCD and I/O expander which encapsulate the I2C transactions. These functions work well individually, but create problems during concurrent operation(for obvious reasons). From what I read online, people seemed to suggest a mutex to lock a particular I2C transfer, to protect it from context switching. 
Could you point me towards some resource explaining the FIFO implementation for I2C? Thanks.

Comment: If you had the mutex around the actual I²C transfer, a stuck I²C device (CLK held low) will stall your host. Consider that. The way you implement a FIFO is completely independent of I²C. It's just a storage space shared by threads and secured by mutexes against simultaneous access.

Comment: This sounds a lot like Linux handles it :) which is good in my book. **but** this doesn't help OP - he's using ready-made drivers which do not support this kind of stuff and in general seem to have poor API.

Comment: Huh? He could **always** implement a worker thread using the existing drivers and just add the FIFO structure on top. That's why I wrote, putting that structure on top only needs 50 lines of C code. It's really only about serializing requests. It's a general pattern, completely independent of I²C.

Comment: I did a bit of digging. As @JanDorniak said, the driver functions use a pre-built function called i2c_driver_install(). This function is using a FIFO, Ring buffer etc in some logic which I can't understand. The functions are defined in the following link:https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/driver/i2c.c
So I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction.
I am also looking at a FIFO implementation as Janka said meanwhile though.

Comment: @RohitGarg FIFO being a FreeRTOS Queue

Comment: The FIFO inside the esp-idf driver is a buffer of 32 bytes present in the I²C hardware. The driver uses it to offload the individual byte transfers to the hardware, so it doesn't have to poll or serve an interrupt  each byte, but only after 32 bytes. This is a useful feature it uses automatically, but not what I'm talking about. Jan Dorniak is right, you could e.g. simply use a FreeRTOS queue for serializing the requests from other threads.